# How to use standalone Master's resources for workers?

Tags: apache-spark

I've installed Apache Spark 1.5.2 (for Hadoop 2.6+). My cluster contains of the following hardware:

- Master: 12 CPU Cores & 128 GB RAM
- Slave1: 12 CPU Cores &  64 GB RAM
- Slave2:  6 CPU Cores &  64 GB RAM

Actually my slaves file has the two entries:

```
slave1_ip
slave2_ip
```

Because my master also has a very "strong" hardware, it wouldn't be used to capacity only by the master threads. So I wanted to ask whether it is possible to provide some of the CPU cores and the RAM from the master machine to a third worker instance...? Thank you!

---

**FIRST ATTEMPT TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

After Jacek Laskowski's answer I set the following settings:

```
spark-defaults.conf (only on Master machine):
  spark.driver.cores=2
  spark.driver.memory=4g

spark-env.sh (on Master):
  SPARK_WORKER_CORES=10
  SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=120g

spark-env.sh (on Slave1):
  SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
  SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=60g

spark-env.sh (on Slave2):
  SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6
  SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=60g
```

I also added the master's ip address to the `slaves` file.

The cluster now contains of 3 worker nodes (slaves + master), that's perfect.

BUT: The web UI shows that there're only 1024m of RAM per node, see Screenshot:
[image]

Can someone say how to fix this? Setting spark.executor.memory will set the same amount of RAM for each machine, which wouldn't be optimal to use as much RAM as possible...! What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's possible. Just limit the number of cores and memory used by the master and run one or more workers on the machine.

Use `conf/spark-defaults.conf` where you can set up `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.driver.cores`. Consult [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

You should however use `conf/spark-env.sh` to set up more than one instance per node using `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES`. Include the other settings as follows:

```
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2g
```

You may also want to set up the number of RAM for executors (per worker) using `spark.executor.memory` or `SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY` (as depicted in the following screenshot).

[image: Memory per Node in Spark Standalone's web UI]

Comment: I set spark.driver.memory to 5g & spark.driver.cores to 4 (of 12). I also added master's ip to the slaves file. When I restart the cluster and open the web ui the "local" worker has 12 cores instead 8!

Comment: Yes, I use the standalone cluster mode. I start the cluster after editing the config files via the start-all.sh script. With your settings, I was able to set all 3 machines as workers, thank you very much! But the problem now is, that each node only works with 1024m of RAM, see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

In spark standalone cluster manager you should put all conf file same like spark-env.sh is same in master and worker so it cant match the configuration and set default memory for worker its 1g

```
spark-defaults.conf (only on Master machine):
spark.driver.cores=2
spark.driver.memory=4g

spark-env.sh (on Master)
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=10 
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=60g

spark-env.sh (on Slave1):
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=10
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=60g

spark-env.sh (on Slave2):
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=10
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=60g
```

and in slaves.conf on each machine as below

```
masterip
slave1ip
slave2ip
```

after above configuration you have 3 workers one on master machine and 2 other on node and your driver is also on master machine.

But we careful you are giving lot of configuration for memory and core if your machines are small resource manager cant allocate resources.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but why wouldn't you set the property spark.executor.memory in spark-default.xml? (OR --executor-memory)
Note this value is 1024MB by default and that is what you seem to be encountering.

The thing is executor.memory is defined at the application level and not at the node level, so there doesnt seem to be a way to start the executors with different cores/memory on diff nodes.